# How to compare 24hrs time format in php?

Tags: php, time

I have time in 24hrs date format. For example

```
$after = 9;
$before = 17;
```

and my enter time is

```
$enterTime = 15;
```

I want to know my enter time `$enterTime` is outside of `$after` and `$before` time.
For this, I am using this code.

```
if(strtotime($enterTime) > strtotime($before) && strtotime($enterTime) < strtotime($after))
{
    echo $enterTime;
    } else {
        echo"jghj";
}
```

Comment: What is the actual format you get the `$after`, `$before` and `$enterTime` times? Because AFAIK if you do `strtotime` with those values in your question it will simple return false.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare like this

```
if(strtotime($enterTime) > strtotime($before) && strtotime($enterTime) < 
strtotime($after))
{
    echo $enterTime;
} else {
    echo"jghj";
}
```

because, strtotime() function takes parameters
Parameters ¶
time:
A date/time string. Valid formats are explained in Date and Time Formats.

now:
The timestamp which is used as a base for the calculation of relative dates.
but you are passing integer value in strtotime(). which is invalid value.

you can compare like so

```
$beforeTime ="14:08:10";
$afterTime ="15:10:00";
if (strtotime(afterTime ) >= strtotime($beforeTime)) {
  echo "ok";
}
```